# R - converting list of characters to list of variables

Tags: r

I have the following code

```
A <- c(1,2,3); B  <- c(2,3,3); C <- c(3,4,5); 
colMeans(rbind (A,A,B,C,C,C,A,A))
```

which when executed returns
[1] 1.88 2.88 3.75

I am trying to get this work for arrays/matrices that I get from an excel file.
When trying to read from the clipboard (MacOSx) using

`read.table(pipe("pbpaste"), sep="\t", header=TRUE)`

I end up getting a dataframe with lists of characters (typeof).

I am fairly new to R so my issue is that these list are characters and not variable names. Tried various ways to convert them to a list of variables so that I could do the "colMeans(rbind())" on them.

Any thoughts ? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `as.numeric`? If you want to convert an entire matrix to numeric you can use `as.numeric(matrix_data)`

Answer (score 0):

You can call the type conversion explicitly after reading from the clipboard:

```
library(tidyverse)

read_delim(pipe("pbpaste"), delim="\t") %>% type_convert()
```

Note that it is recommended to always read data from files stores somewhere. The clipboard makes the code not reproducible anymore.